# Do I need to use individual fastlane metadata files?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, flutter-ios-build, fastfile

Do I need to supply individual metadata files if I am using Deliverfile? Can't I supply all the values found in the metadata files - can't I provide them inside the Deliverfile?